# Different results from suffix and prefix subrules in grammar

Tags: antlr4

I have a ANTLR4 grammar that has a few rules trying to match partial application of expressions in a language. Simplifying them, the rules look like this:

```
grammar PartialExpression;

program
    :   (function '.')+
    ;

function
    :   name '=>' expression (';' expression)*
    ;

name
    :   SYMBOL
    ;

expression
    :   functionCall
    |   closure
    |   literal
    |   expression binaryOperator expression
    |   unaryOperator expression
    |   '(' expression ')'
    ;

functionCall
    :   name
    ;

closure
    :   '[' '=>'? expression (';' expression)* ']'
    |   '[' partialExpression ']'  
    ;

partialExpression
    :   binaryOperator expression # leftPartialExpression
    |   expression binaryOperator # rightPartialExpression
    ;

unaryOperator
    :   ('-' | '+' | '~')
    ;

binaryOperator
    :   ('=' | '<' | '>' | '@' | '^' | '+' | '-' | '*' | '/' | '$' | '!' | ':' | '|')+
    ;

literal
    :   NUMBER
    ;

SYMBOL
    :   ('a'..'z'| 'A'..'Z')+
    ;

NUMBER
    :   '-'? [0-9]+ ('.' [0-9]+)? ([eE] '-'? [0-9]+)?
    ;

WS
    :   [ \n\r\t\,] -> skip
    ;

COMMENT
    :   '%' ~[\r\n]* -> skip
    ;
```

Everything parses well, except for the last sub-rule in `partialExpression`, which despite appearing correctly parsed in the TestRig, gives back an `expression`, followed by a `binaryOperator` as expected, but now containing three children: the correct `expression`, the correct `binaryOperator` and an empty `expression` instead of simply whatever `expression` it was supposed to be. The code used to test it is:

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker;

public class TestPartialExpression 
{
    public static class Printer extends PartialExpressionBaseListener 
    {
        @Override public void enterRightPartialExpression(PartialExpressionParser.RightPartialExpressionContext ctx)
        {
            System.out.println("Right Expression: " + ctx.expression().getText());
        }

        @Override public void enterLeftPartialExpression(PartialExpressionParser.LeftPartialExpressionContext ctx)
        {
            System.out.println("Left Expression: " + ctx.expression().getText());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream("fc => [m *].");
        PartialExpressionLexer lexer = new PartialExpressionLexer(input);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        PartialExpressionParser parser = new PartialExpressionParser(tokens);
        ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
        Printer printer = new Printer();

        walker.walk(printer, parser.program());
    }
}
```

Expected output from the code is `m`. Actual output is `m*`.

Is this something expected due to the nature of the rule being a left recursion?

Comment: Can you post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) including some input?

Comment: @BartKiers, I have added a complete grammar and test code to the example. I also found out that it only happens under ANTLR 4.2. Under 4.2.1, it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

I converted to program to C# and removed the `static` from the printer class and the output is `m` as you expected.

There are also only two children in the RightPartialExpressionContext.

Maybe you could paste your output or post a screenshot of a debugging window showing the three children?

```
    private static void partialExpressionTest()
    {
        AntlrInputStream input = new AntlrInputStream("fc => [m *].");
        PartialExpressionLexer lexer = new PartialExpressionLexer(input);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        PartialExpressionParser parser = new PartialExpressionParser(tokens);
        ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
        Printer printer = new Printer();

        walker.Walk(printer, parser.program());
        // prints "Right Expression: m"
    }


public class Printer : PartialExpressionBaseListener
{
    override public void EnterRightPartialExpression(PartialExpressionParser.RightPartialExpressionContext ctx)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Right Expression: " + ctx.expression().GetText());
    }

    override public void EnterLeftPartialExpression(PartialExpressionParser.LeftPartialExpressionContext ctx)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Left Expression: " + ctx.expression().GetText());
    }
}
```